# How to pull past 30 day data?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query below where I want to pull data in the past 30 days but the problem is I don't want to pull from today's date but rather the past 30 days of a specific date say 3/1/2019. How can I do this?

select *
from TStudy
where StudyDate >= dateadd(day,-30,getdate())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would just put the date into the `where` clause:

```
where StudyDate < '20190301' and
      StudyDate >= dateadd(day, -30, '20190301')
```